# Print and saving map with tiled and dynamic layers in ArcGIS using JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing

I want to print this map. Can anyone please suggest to me how to print and save the displaying pap in ArcGIS using JavaScript?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7,IE=9" />
    <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples on iOS devices-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title> World Street Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.2/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.2/js/esri/css/esri.css" />

    <style>
      html,body,#map,.map.container{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        height:100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">var djConfig = {parseOnLoad: true};</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=3.2"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      dojo.require("esri.map");

      var map;

      function init() {
        var initExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent({"xmin":-17731,"ymin":6710077,"xmax":-12495,"ymax":6712279,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100}});
        map = new esri.Map("map",{extent:initExtent});

       //Add the world street map layer to the map. View the ArcGIS Online site for services http://arcgisonline/home/search.html?t=content&f=typekeywords:service    
        var basemap = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer");
        map.addLayer(basemap);
        dynamicMapServiceLayer = newesri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://maverick.arcgis.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_WGS84/MapServer");  

        dojo.connect(map, 'onLoad', function(theMap) {
          //resize the map when the browser resizes
          dojo.connect(window, 'resize', map,map.resize);
        });
     }
     dojo.addOnLoad(init);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body class="claro">
    <div id="map">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please enter the code in proper format

Comment: I was doing this few weeks ago. Please write which version of arcgis api are you using, and what server-side language are you fluent in. and as @Sunil wrote before - reformat your code.

Comment: @Mayank and please cut off your IP adress from code. It is very unsecure to do such a things.

Comment: i am using arcgis 10.1 and language is java script.

Comment: @Mayank I was asking about **server side** programing language - if you wanna to do this by your own.

Comment: i dont want to use any server side language ,as arcguis tutorial they simply use java script and print the map .i want to do that.

Answer (score 7):

In ArcGIS 10.1 there is option to print map by `Export Web Map Task Service`. If you are using API v. 3.x you can just use `Print Task` from API.

The sample of using dijit with PrintTask can be found here:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm#jssamples/widget_print_webmap.html

or just class description in here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi_start.htm

**EDIT**

if I were you I would do it like this:

1) you have to define URL adress to your print service:

```
var url ='http://servicesbeta4.esri.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/ExportWebMap/GPServer/Export Web Map Task';
var printTask = new esri.tasks.PrintTask(url);
```

2) then you have to define callback function for print task execute:

```
var printResult = function(result){
 console.log(result)
}
```

3) you have to set new print object with your previously parameters and your existing map object:

```
var params = new esri.tasks.PrintParameters();
  params.map = map;
```

4) and finally execute print task

```
printTask.execute(params, printResult);
```

FYI it is only general idea of this task. Now you should wrap with your own JS code.

Comment: yes i have already gone through with this ,but there is predefined script  like print and printdijit like that, i want a simple print button and then i want to print my map .i have that link before but cudn't get how to customized it ,as i am new in arcgis .so could any one please share one demo example for that.

Comment: @Mayank OK. I edited the code. Can I ask you to please mark the question as solved and award the points?